# Iniciar todos os CheckBoxes de um JTree selecionados

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtree

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer para iniciar a classe já com todos os checkboxes marcados, encontrei esta classe e utilizei:

```
package CustonComponents;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.EventListener;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class JCheckBoxTree extends JTree {    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4194122328392241790L;

    JCheckBoxTree selfPointer = this;

    // Defining data structure that will enable to fast check-indicate the state of each node
    // It totally replaces the "selection" mechanism of the JTree
    private class CheckedNode {

        boolean isSelected;
        boolean hasChildren;
        boolean allChildrenSelected;

        public CheckedNode(boolean isSelected_, boolean hasChildren_, boolean allChildrenSelected_) {
            isSelected = isSelected_;
            hasChildren = hasChildren_;
            allChildrenSelected = allChildrenSelected_;
        }
    }
    HashMap<TreePath, CheckedNode> nodesCheckingState;
    HashSet<TreePath> checkedPaths = new HashSet<TreePath>();

    // Defining a new event type for the checking mechanism and preparing event-handling mechanism
    protected EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();

    public class CheckChangeEvent extends EventObject {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8100230309044193368L;

        public CheckChangeEvent(Object source) {
            super(source);
        }
    }

    public interface CheckChangeEventListener extends EventListener {

        public void checkStateChanged(CheckChangeEvent event);
    }

    public void addCheckChangeEventListener(CheckChangeEventListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(CheckChangeEventListener.class, listener);
    }

    public void removeCheckChangeEventListener(CheckChangeEventListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(CheckChangeEventListener.class, listener);
    }

    void fireCheckChangeEvent(CheckChangeEvent evt) {
        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
            if (listeners[i] == CheckChangeEventListener.class) {
                ((CheckChangeEventListener) listeners[i + 1]).checkStateChanged(evt);
            }
        }
    }

    // Override
    public void setModel(TreeModel newModel) {
        super.setModel(newModel);
        resetCheckingState();
    }

    // New method that returns only the checked paths (totally ignores original "selection" mechanism)
    public TreePath[] getCheckedPaths() {
        return checkedPaths.toArray(new TreePath[checkedPaths.size()]);
    }

    // Returns true in case that the node is selected, has children but not all of them are selected
    public boolean isSelectedPartially(TreePath path) {
        CheckedNode cn = nodesCheckingState.get(path);
        return cn.isSelected && cn.hasChildren && !cn.allChildrenSelected;
    }

    private void resetCheckingState() {
        nodesCheckingState = new HashMap<TreePath, CheckedNode>();
        checkedPaths = new HashSet<TreePath>();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) getModel().getRoot();
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        addSubtreeToCheckingStateTracking(node);
    }

    // Creating data structure of the current model for the checking mechanism
    private void addSubtreeToCheckingStateTracking(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
        TreeNode[] path = node.getPath();
        TreePath tp = new TreePath(path);
        CheckedNode cn = new CheckedNode(false, node.getChildCount() > 0, false);
        nodesCheckingState.put(tp, cn);
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildCount(); i++) {
            addSubtreeToCheckingStateTracking((DefaultMutableTreeNode) tp.pathByAddingChild(node.getChildAt(i)).getLastPathComponent());
        }
    }

    // Overriding cell renderer by a class that ignores the original "selection" mechanism
    // It decides how to show the nodes due to the checking-mechanism
    private class CheckBoxCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TreeCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7341833835878991719L;
        JCheckBox checkBox;

        public CheckBoxCellRenderer() {
            super();
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            checkBox = new JCheckBox();
            add(checkBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
                boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
                boolean hasFocus) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
            Object obj = node.getUserObject();
            TreePath tp = new TreePath(node.getPath());
            CheckedNode cn = nodesCheckingState.get(tp);
            if (cn == null) {
                return this;
            }
            checkBox.setSelected(cn.isSelected);
            checkBox.setText(obj.toString());
            checkBox.setOpaque(cn.isSelected && cn.hasChildren && !cn.allChildrenSelected);
            return this;
        }
    }

    public JCheckBoxTree() {
        super();
        // Disabling toggling by double-click
        this.setToggleClickCount(0);
        // Overriding cell renderer by new one defined above
        CheckBoxCellRenderer cellRenderer = new CheckBoxCellRenderer();
        this.setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);

        // Overriding selection model by an empty one
        DefaultTreeSelectionModel dtsm = new DefaultTreeSelectionModel() {            
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -8190634240451667286L;

            // Totally disabling the selection mechanism
            public void setSelectionPath(TreePath path) {
            }

            public void addSelectionPath(TreePath path) {
            }

            public void removeSelectionPath(TreePath path) {
            }

            public void setSelectionPaths(TreePath[] pPaths) {
            }
        };
        // Calling checking mechanism on mouse click
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                TreePath tp = selfPointer.getPathForLocation(arg0.getX(), arg0.getY());                
                if (tp == null) {
                    return;
                }
                boolean checkMode = !nodesCheckingState.get(tp).isSelected;
                checkSubTree(tp, checkMode);
                updatePredecessorsWithCheckMode(tp, checkMode);
                // Firing the check change event
                fireCheckChangeEvent(new CheckChangeEvent(new Object()));
                // Repainting tree after the data structures were updated
                selfPointer.repaint();
            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        this.setSelectionModel(dtsm);
    }

    // When a node is checked/unchecked, updating the states of the predecessors
    protected void updatePredecessorsWithCheckMode(TreePath tp, boolean check) {
        TreePath parentPath = tp.getParentPath();
        // If it is the root, stop the recursive calls and return
        if (parentPath == null) {
            return;
        }
        CheckedNode parentCheckedNode = nodesCheckingState.get(parentPath);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) parentPath.getLastPathComponent();
        parentCheckedNode.allChildrenSelected = true;
        parentCheckedNode.isSelected = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < parentNode.getChildCount(); i++) {
            TreePath childPath = parentPath.pathByAddingChild(parentNode.getChildAt(i));
            CheckedNode childCheckedNode = nodesCheckingState.get(childPath);
            // It is enough that even one subtree is not fully selected
            // to determine that the parent is not fully selected
            if (!childCheckedNode.allChildrenSelected) {
                parentCheckedNode.allChildrenSelected = false;
            }
            // If at least one child is selected, selecting also the parent
            if (childCheckedNode.isSelected) {
                parentCheckedNode.isSelected = true;
            }
        }
        if (parentCheckedNode.isSelected) {
            checkedPaths.add(parentPath);
        } else {
            checkedPaths.remove(parentPath);
        }
        // Go to upper predecessor
        updatePredecessorsWithCheckMode(parentPath, check);
    }

    // Recursively checks/unchecks a subtree
    protected void checkSubTree(TreePath tp, boolean check) {
        CheckedNode cn = nodesCheckingState.get(tp);
        cn.isSelected = check;
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tp.getLastPathComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildCount(); i++) {
            checkSubTree(tp.pathByAddingChild(node.getChildAt(i)), check);
        }
        cn.allChildrenSelected = check;
        if (check) {
            checkedPaths.add(tp);
        } else {
            checkedPaths.remove(tp);
        }
    }   

}
```

Classe de Teste

```
package checkboxtree;

public class NovoJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NovoJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jCheckBoxTree1 = new CustonComponents.JCheckBoxTree();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jCheckBoxTree1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 152, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 245, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NovoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NovoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NovoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NovoJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NovoJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private CustonComponents.JCheckBoxTree jCheckBoxTree1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Gostaria que quando inicializasse a classe viessem todos selecionados !!

Comment: Pode adicionar um exemplo que seja reproduzível? Não consegui reproduzir este código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O próprio código postado tem explicações sobre seu uso. Na classe `CheckedNode` diz o seguinte:

> Defining data structure that will enable to fast check-indicate the state of each node.
>   It totally replaces the "selection" mechanism of the JTree.

Em resumo, esta classe é responsável por indicar o estado dos *JCheckBoxes* em cada Node. Perceba que ela tem o seguinte construtor:

```
    public CheckedNode(boolean isSelected_, boolean hasChildren_, boolean allChildrenSelected_) {
        isSelected = isSelected_;
        hasChildren = hasChildren_;
        allChildrenSelected = allChildrenSelected_;
    }
```

Ele recebe 3 parâmetros:

- o primeiro indica se o checkbox do node está selecionado(checked);
- o segundo indica se o node possui "filhos". Note que essa verificação é feita com `node.getChildCount() > 0`, ou seja, verifica se o número de nodes internos é maior que zero, se for maior, retorna true, o que indica que possui sub-elementos.
- o terceiro indica se, caso o node tenha "filhos"(outros nodes ou os checkboxes), todos estão selecionados. Esse controle serve mais para salientar o background mais escuro, indicando que nem todos os elementos daquele node estão checados, mas há alguns que foram.

Entendendo como essa classe funciona, basta alterar a forma como o método `addSubtreeToCheckingStateTracking()` está iniciando a classe `CheckedNode`. Esta classe é chamada várias vezes, pois ela é quem monta a estrutura de todos os nodes da `JTree`.

Na linha:

```
CheckedNode cn = new CheckedNode(false, node.getChildCount() > 0, false);
```

Altere para:

```
CheckedNode cn = new CheckedNode(true, node.getChildCount() > 0, true);
```

Desta forma, você está indicando que quer que tanto o checkbox do node, quanto dos nodes "filhos" estejam marcados quando a tela abrir.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo... Se ainda puder me ajudar, como eu poderia por exemplo bloquear todos os nos para ficarem não clicaves, enquanto eu executo um procedimento, apos isso eles voltariam a ficar clicavis, Tentei o setEnabled mas não funcionou..

Comment: @UlissesGimenes ai é outra duvida diferente da pergunta feita. Você pode marcar esta como aceita, clicando no `v` do lado esquerdo, e criar outra pergunta questionando sobre esta nova duvida. Isso é necessário para manter as perguntas objetivas ao problema que foi apresentado. Não esqueça de linkar essa aqui na nova pergunta.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138262/iniciar-todos-os-checkboxes-de-um-jtree-selecionados/138319?noredirect=1#comment286802_138319

Comment: Boa tarde diegofm, como havíamos conversado sobre a marcação das caixas de seleção, teste como tinha me dito, e funcionou.. mas apenas mostra os checks marcados, mas quando vou executar para mostrar no console qual esta marcado, e como se não tivessem marcados..