# Bloquear jTree enquanto executa procedimento

Tags: java

Boa tarde pessoal, gostaria de saber como eu poderia bloquear(Não clicavel) todos os nos da arvore enquanto eu executo um procedimento, apos isso eu desbloquearia os nos..

Encontrei a classe JCheckBoxTree e estou utilizando, mas nao consegui com setEnabled..

Segue link de uma pergunta que se referencia a esta contendo o código..

[CÓDIGO DA CLASSE JCheckBoxTree](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138262/iniciar-todos-os-checkboxes-de-um-jtree-selecionados/138319?noredirect=1#comment286802_138319)

Obrigado...

Comment: Pesquise por SwingWorker, provavelmente você vai precisar usar essa classe.

Comment: Mas já esta utilizando o SwingWorker, quando clico em sincronizar ele ativa o SwingWorker e quando termina ele finaliza, durante este processo gostaria de bloquear para não ser possivel clicar na arvore, mas continua clicavel. mesmo não fazendo efeito na sincronização.

Comment: Então adicione o código que você fez. No da outra pergunta não tem nada de swingworker.

Comment: Ah tah aquele era um exemplo

Comment: Adicione apenas um [mcve], para que seja possivel simular  e testar o código, como na outra pergunta.

Comment: Verifica se ajuda, é a minha classe real, na qual utilizo a jtree.....

Comment: É só isso mais a classe da outra pergunta?

Comment: Ah tah, não aquele eu utilizei como teste, esta é a implementação real..

Comment: Veja esse vídeo, como está o funcionamento, enquento eu estou sincronizando as checks ficam clicaveis... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqxMh2mZz-Q&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Mas o código  da pergunta então não é reproduzivel. Para poder fazer uma boa resposta, como no outro caso, é preciso testar o código como ele está funcionando. Sem um [mcve] fica quase impossivel sugerir algo. Se o código funcional não cabe aqui, poste-o em algum site e adicione o link para conferencia na pergunta.

Comment: Sou novo ainda não entendo bem o site, e a classe está dentro de um projeto grande...

Comment: São varias classes para funcionar

Comment: Vou tentar fazer com base no exemplo da outra pergunta. Qualquer adaptação para seu código real ficará por sua conta, pode ser?

Comment: Pode sim, muito obrigado..

Comment: Consegui fazer, mas... Eu não se se foi a forma correta.. eu utilizei uma variável estática boolean e testei no evento do mouse da classe jtree..

Comment: Sinceramente não sei como te ajudar, você está usando um jtree customizado, o que implica que, pra fazer esse bloqueio, precisa compreender exatamente o funcionamento da jtree que foi customizada. Mas pode aparecer alguém que te ajude, com mais entendimento sobre este componente, só aguardar :)

Comment: Obrigado, sem problemas.. Agradeço muito a ajuda que tive...